# Matrix without the matrix function

Tags: r, matrix, rbind

I m trying to create a matrix in R without using matrix function I tried 
this but it works just for 2 rows how do I specify nrows  I have no idea

```
matrix2<-function(n)
{ 
  d<-n/2

  v1<-c(1:d)
  v2<-c(d +1:n)
  x<- rbind(v1,v2)
  return(x)

  }
```

I want to create a matrix without using the matrix function and byrow not bycolmun 
exemple 
a function I enter number of columns and the dimension N in my exemple and in return it creates a matrix

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    7    8
```

for exepmle

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your post and make if a full reproducible example which shows the actual and the desired output.

Comment: i edited it now @lukeA

Comment: Why do you want to create a matrix without using the matrix function? Can you show an example of input and expected output based on that?

Comment: But why not use the matrix function?

Comment: @Heroka it is a question in the lesson  i just took

Comment: Use `dim()`. And `t()` if necessary...

Comment: `cbind()` or `rbind()` some vectors?

Comment: @Jimbou  yeah and i need to specify row numbers that's the problem the function i posted works for 2 rows

Comment: Oh, I read too fast. As it's a lesson you should try it by your own. But the comment by @ZéLoff is worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a matrix for a specified number of columns. I wasn't sure what you meant with dimension N.

```
matrix2 <- function(N, columns){

  d<-ceiling(N/columns) # rounds up to first integer

  x <- c()
  i <- 1

  for(row in 1:d){
    x <- rbind(x, c(i:(i+columns-1)))
    i <- i+columns
  }

  return(x)
}

> matrix2(8,2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    7    8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an indirection via a list. Then you can also set both, the column and the row number. And how the matrix is filled, row wise or column wise.

```
matrix2<-function(n,m,V,byRow=T){
  if(length(V) != n*m ) warning("length of the vector and rows*columns differs" )
  # split the vector 
  if(byRow) r <- n
  if(!byRow) r <- m
  fl <- 1:r # how often you have to split
  fg <- sort(rep_len(fl,length(V))) # create a "splitting-vector"
  L <- split(V,fg)
  # convert the list to a matrix
  if(byRow)  res <- do.call(rbind,L)  
  if(!byRow) res <-  do.call(cbind,L)  
  rownames(res) <- colnames(res) <- NULL 
  res #output
}

matrix2(2,4,1:8,F)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    4    6    8

matrix2(2,4,1:8,T)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
```